# I have an issue related to Android Studio that affects Unity

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk, unity-remote

When I open Unity and try to connect my game, Unity Remote, to try it, a message appears: **Set-up Android SDK path to make Android remote work.** Note that I have connected both Unity and Android Studio to the same SDK path.

On the other hand, in Android Studio, this message appears to me:**an existing android sdk was detected. the setup wizard will only download missing or outdated sdk components.** I hope you can give me a solution because I searched a lot and did not find anything.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZGwr.png)

((https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbRAe.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeQ0T.png)

I watched many videos and followed many steps, but it did not work. Among the things I did was I tried to change the path to the sdk, but despite that, the same problem appeared.